# Nib-defined toolbar items in the customization palette

Tags: cocoa, nstoolbar

I'm finding that with a toolbar defined in a nib, the toolbar delegate's `toolbar:itemForItemIdentifier:willBeInsertedIntoToolbar:` method doesn't get called. So how can I tell if one of my custom items is going into the customization palette? The docs say that in the nib case I can still use that method to "augment functionality", but I'm not getting any augmenting.

**Update:** I tried implementing that method in a subclass rather than the delegate. It does get called, and only when setting up the customize sheet, but strangely `toolbar` and `itemIdentifier` are nil for all items.

**Update 2:** I'm getting around this by overriding `viewWillMoveToWindow:` in my custom view, and checking whether the new window has a toolbar. I'm seeing the views get moved back and forth between toolbarless and toolbarred winodows, which suggests that this may actually be a better solution than a delegate method that only gets called when the item is created.